# Theorem for which polarization in a dielectric ellipsoid inside a uniform electric field is constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, dielectric

I read on textbook that there is a theorem for which, given a dielectric ellipsoid in a external uniform electric field $\bf{E}$, under special conditions on the orientation of $\bf{E}$ with respect to the axes of the ellipsoid, the polarization $\bf{P}$ inside the ellipsoid is constant everywhere.

Can anyone suggest what does this theorem exactly state and why does it hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Dielectric Ellipsoid - UCF Physics](https://physics.ucf.edu/%7Erep/EDIII/LL8sec8.pptx) (p.15):

> Theorem:
>
> Whatever the ratio of the semiaxes a,b,c, the internal field of a dielectric ellipsoid placed in a uniform external field is uniform.

According to p. 23 the orientation of the field wrt the axes doesn't matter. (This follows by superposition if you can prove it in the axial directions.)

I can't give you a "why", some proofs are computational.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The file posted only contains nine pages, are there more?

Comment: Fixed. (Somehow I linked to an incomplete version.)